# Dropdown menu for drawer header [Flutter]

Tags: android, flutter, dart, drop-down-menu

Hi what I want to do is make a dropdown menu inside of a drawer header but when I tried I got constraint errors also Im curious how can I pass 2 values into it so when pressed the text will change according to it

My code:

```
return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.20,
            child: DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Text(
                                widget.name,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.amber,
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 3,
                            ),
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Text(
                                widget.name,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                AppListItems(Icons.favorite, 'Text', SecondRoute()),
                AppListItems(Icons.favorite, 'Text', SecondRoute()),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

This is how it looks like and where I want the dropdown menu to be:

[image]

Any help would be great, thanks in advance

Comment: you want to display dropdown inside drawer header?

Comment: @ravindras.patil yes that is correct

Comment: Can you show the error that is coming up. I think error is coming up bcz of some code

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you.

```
 drawer: Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children: [
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.20,
          child: DrawerHeader(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text(
                              'widget.name',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.amber,
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 3,
                          ),
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text(
                              'widget.name',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: DropdownButton<String>(
                      value: dropdownValue,
                      isDense: true,
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                      elevation: 16,
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                      underline: Container(
                        height: 2,
                        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                      ),
                      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          dropdownValue = newValue!;
                        });
                      },
                      items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
                          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: value,
                          child: Text(value),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.favorite,
              ),
              Icon(
                Icons.favorite,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Your dropdown-> [image]

Comment: Well debatable because I want to change the 2 texts bigger and smaller one, so the widget.name is also included as a dropdown menu option